# Save .JSON file to database using laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-4

I am very new to Laravel and PHP in general, most of what I have worked on has been relative to online tutorials. I know how to save single items like a username or password to my database but I am clueless when it comes to storing an entire file.This is how my database is currently formatted in my migration file:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->string('remember_token')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Any help is appreciated, let me know is more information about my project is needed.

Edit:

Example of JSON file similar to what I will be using:

```
{"Date 1": {
  "Item 1": {
    "para1": "word",
    "para2": 100,
  },
  "Item 2": { 
    "para1": "word",
    "para2": 100,
  },
  "Item 3": {
    "para1": "word",
    "para2": 100,
  }
  }
"Date 2": {
  "Item 1": {
    "para1": "word",
    "para2": 100,
  },
  "Item 2": { 
    "para1": "word",
    "para2": 100,
  },
  "Item 3": {
    "para1": "word",
    "para2": 100,
  }
}}
```

Comment: Please can you give us an example of the json file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this line to your migration file:

```
$table->string('json');
```

Refresh your migrations

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

Add to your user object:

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
    public $json;
}
```

Set the property as usual (a setter is recommended but not provided in this example)

```
$user = new User;
$user->json = json_encode( array('test-key' => 'test-data' ) );
```

Save

```
$user->save();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm a little confused on the `'test-key' => 'test-data'` part. What exactly is that doing? How could I set the example JSON in my question as default after creating the new user?

Comment: That `$user->json = ` line is just where I'm setting the json on the object. `json_encode` turns a PHP array into a JSON string. Depending on what form your json is in, you will just need to assign it to the `$user->json` property.